# IE Z-INDEX Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, z-index

**Issue**: Slideshow

**Details**: There's a frame (which is just a transparent PNG around the slideshow)

**What I'm trying to do:**
Make the frame over the image and caption background but make the link and nav-balls on top of the png.

It works like I want in other browsers except for IE. I read more on the z-index bug for IE but that didn't help. Any suggestions or help is VERY very much appreciated.

**Issue resolved.**

Comment: Can you either update the link or post the relevant code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make navigation dots clickable, apply styles:

```
display:block; position:relative; // to frame

z-index:1001; //to .nivo-controlNav
```

To *learn more* link i suggest:

1) delete all z-index property that applies to `.nivo-caption`

2) add shadow div with `z-index: 87 /*(87 for example)*/` below frame

Answer (score 1):

The issue for this is that IE don't follow the z-indexing of an image, no matter how small or big the z-index you put in your image, IE will still follow the hierarchy level of the elements.  If you really want to use z-indexing of an image in IE, you can wrap the image inside a div and put the z-index on the div, this will follow the right z-indexing on all browsers including IE.

```
// will not follow in IE
<div>first div</div>
<img style="z-index: -1;" src="image.png" />
<div>my div</div>

// will follow in IE
<div>first div</div>
<div style="z-index: -1;"><img src="image.png" /></div>
<div>my div</div>
```

Comment: This still did not resolve the issue in my case. I'm using Nivo Slider, and have put the "frame" inside the dive with a negative -1 z-index but it still covers the links. Have a look at my link and as you see the slideshow, I need to keep each slide's 'description background' behind the frame but bring the links "Learn More" and the navigation dots infront/ontop of the 'frame' image. Any other ideas? Maybe I'm implementing this wrong =\ Again it's only an issue within IE so I'm using a IE conditional comment to include an ie only stylesheet